# How do I hide XAML control after a user interacts within a WebView control

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have an app that uses javascript to call another projects native c# class methods from within the WebView control (very similar to [this](https://github.com/qmatteoq/HybridApp-UWP/blob/master/HybridApp.UWP/MainPage.xaml.cs) github project)

I use the AddWedAllowedObject method inside the OnNavigationStarting event.

How do I hide/show XAML controls from the native c# class methods that are being called?  I cannot refer to the Page class in the other projects because of circular dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The object passed into **AddWebAllowedObject** must be imported from a [Windows Runtime component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt188216.aspx) that is separate from the app assembly. This is necessary for the **AllowForWeb** attribute to be property identified by the [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) security subsystem. If you use a class from your app project, **AddWebAllowedObject** does not work.

For more info, see [`WebView.AddWebAllowedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.AddWebAllowedObject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

As you know,we can not refer to the Page class in the other projects because of circular dependency.

As a workaround, we can sent a string to the page from Html. And according to the string to hide/show XAML controls.

> A hosted HTML page can fire the ScriptNotify event in your Windows Store app when the page calls window.external.notify and passes a string parameter.

For more info, see [WebView.ScriptNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify).

For example:

```
<WebView Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScriptNotify="Web_ScriptNotify"
          NavigationStarting="OnNavigationStarting" x:Name="Web" Source="ms-appx-web:///WebPage.html" />
<Ellipse Name="MyEllipse" Fill="Red" Height="200" Width="200"></Ellipse>
```

In code behind:

```
private void Web_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == "Collapsed")
    {
        MyEllipse.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        MyEllipse.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Edit the function in WebPage.html:

```
function showToast() {
    window.external.notify('Collapsed');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is just what I was looking for.